# Failed to download summaries index for snapshot in Coverity

Tags: coverity

I am unable to run eclipse coverity plugin as it says the snapshot has no summaries data. Is there any workaround for this ?

Update:
Now getting

Review the snapshot list in Coverity Connect and enable the"Has Analysis Summaries" column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need to do

1. Go in to configuration and enable 'Desktop Analysis' for all streams that you want to use.
2. Go to your source directory and blow away your intermediate directory.
3. `cov-build --desktop --dir idir <make commands>`
4. cov-analyze and commit as usual
5. You'll be good to go

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I am getting "Review the snapshot list in Coverity Connect and enable the
"Has Analysis Summaries" column.  It may be necessary to
enable Desktop Analysis in the stream configuration and then
commit a new snapshot."  error. 
I can't change the configuration on the server. Is there anything that I can do in the plugin or locally?

Comment: Nope, you need to change the server configuration.